# Prevent particular columns to add a new row

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in columns A-D for instance and another data in columns E-Z. I want to add a row to a spreadsheet (to columns E-Z in particular), but leave the data in columns A-D unchanged. Same with deleting a row. Any suggestion please?

Thanks,
Arthur

Comment: Don't insert a row and insert cells, shifting down, instead

Comment: that's highly inconvenient, as the actual data goes much further than Z..

Comment: Can you help me understand this? How do you add a row to columns E-Z and exclude A-D? Do you mean you want to shift all the data in E-Z down but keep the data in A-D unchanged?This means they are unrelated for the same row. If the data in A-D is unrelated to the data in E-Z for the same row, why don't you use 2 different sheets?

Comment: Use 2 different sheets.

Comment: Tehscript, because the whole layout requires it to be there.. othewise I would surely just use another sheet. Is it generally possible to create the independent area in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a row includes all columns and a column includes all rows. You cannot insert a partial row or a partial column. As @cybermetic.nomad said, you need to insert cells, not rows.

**The easiest way to insert cells (assuming you have Excel 2007 or above) is:**

1) Select the cell in column E that you want to be below the new cells

2) Hold down your "Shift" key and press the right arrow key to select the rest of the cells in the row.

3) If you need to insert cells on more than one row, use your arrow key to select the correct number of rows.

4) While holding down your "Alt" key, press "h", then "i", then "i" again

5) In the popup box, make sure "Shift cells down" is selected

6) Click "OK"

7) That's it

**To Delete cells:**

1) Select a the first cell you want to delete

2) Hold down your "Shift" key and press the right arrow key to select the rest of the cells in the row.

3) If you need to insert cells on more than one row, use your arrow key to select the correct number of rows.

4) While holding down your "Alt" key, press "h", then "d", then "d" again

5) In the popup box, select whichever option is appropriate for you

6) Click "OK"

7) That's it